# Algorithm for sorting a two-dimensional array based on similarities of adjecent objects

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I'm writing a program that is supposed
to sort a number of square tiles (of which
each side is colored in one of five colors—red, orange,
blue, green and yellow), that are laying next to each other
(eg 8 rows and 12 columns) in a way that as many sides with
the same color connect as possible.
So, for instance, a tile with right side colored
red should have a tile on the right that has a red left-side.)

The result is evaluated by counting how many non-matching pairs
of sides exist on the board. I'm pretty much done with the actual program;
I just have some trouble with my sorting algorithm. Right now I'm using
Bubble-sort based algorithm, that compares every piece on the board
with every other piece, and if switching those two reduces the amount of
non-matching pairs of sides on the board, it switches them. Here a
abstracted version of the sorting function, as it is now:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < DimensionOfBoard.cx * DimensionOfBoard.cy ; i++)
    for(int j = 0 ; j < DimensionOfBoard.cx * DiemsionOfBoard.cy ; j++)
    {
        // Comparing a piece with itself is useless
        if(i == j)
            continue;

        // v1 is the amount of the nonmatching sides of both pieces
        // (max is 8, since we have 2 pieces with 4 sides each (duh))
        int v1 = Board[i].GetNonmatchingSides() + Board[j].GetNonmatchingSides();

        // Switching the pieces, if this decreases the value of the board 
        // (increases the amount of nonmatching sides) we'll switch back)
        SwitchPieces(Board[i], Board[j]);

        // If switching worsened the situation ...
        if(v1 < Board[i].GetNonmathcingSides() + Board[j].GetNonmatchingSides())
            // ... we switch back to the initial state
            SwitchPieces(Board[i], Board[j]);
    }
```

As an explanation: Board is a pointer to an array of Piece Object. Each Piece has
four Piece-pointers that point to the four adjacent pieces (or NULL, if the Piece is
a side/corner piece.) And switching actually doesn't switch the pieces itself, but
rather switches the colors. (Instead of exchanging the pieces it scrapes off the color
of both and switches that.)

This algorithm doesn't work too bad, it significantly improves the value of the
board, but it doesn't optimize it as it should. I assume it's because side and corner
pieces can't have move than three/two wrong adjacent pieces, since one/two side(s)
are empty. I tried to compensate for that (by multiplying Board[i].GetMatchingPieces()
with Board[i].GetHowManyNonemptySides() before comparing), but that didn't help a bit.
And that's where I need help. I don't know very many sorting algorithms, let alone
those that work with two-dimensional arrays. So can anyone of you know about
an algorithmic concept that might help me to improve my work? Or can anyone see a
problem that I haven't found yet? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Dave!  Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I'm not sure I would call this a sorting problem. You aren't actually placing pieces in order according to a pair-wise comparison function. (Put another way, whether two switch two pieces does not depend on the pieces themselves, but rather on what surrounds each piece.) This is more of a state space search, where each state is a board configuration (arrangement of pieces) and you are looking for the best configuration by considering pairwise piece switches. Take a look at alpha-beta and other heuristic search algorithms.

Comment: I think you might only need a triangular loop: `for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) { for (j = i + 1; j < N; ++j) { /* ... */ } }`.

Comment: I think you've gone in the completely wrong direction.  I don't think "sorting" is the right way to go here.  There should be a simplish algorithm for placing them in the right places the first time.

Comment: Wait, do you "paint" the pieces, or do they come pre-painted.  Also, if they come prepainted, can they be rotated?

Comment: FYI: the problem with your alorithm is it can "rotate" the positions of two elements, but not more than that.  A->B->C and C->A.

Comment: Fairly certain adding `NonMatchingSides` would bias the health function instead of improving it.

Comment: Your description of 'scraping the colors off troubles me.   That actually transforms the original pieces.   For instance it could turn one with 3 blues and a green side to an all blue piece.   Is that allowed in the problem domain?

Comment: @AShelly Yes, but in this particular example it would also transform an all blue piece into one with three blues and a green side. Since the only way to distinguish between pieces is by their color, exchanging the color is identical to exchanging pieces (except I don't have to cope with messy pointer updates).

Comment: @Mooing Duck The pieces come pre-painted, and I may not rotate them.

Answer (score 0):

if there was a switch you have to re-evaluate a board, because there might be previous positions where now you could find an enhancement.

Note that you are going to find only a local minimum with those swappings. You might won't be able to find any enhancements but that doesn't mean that's the best board configuration.

One way to find a better configuration is to shuffle a board and search for a new local minumum, or use an algorithm-skeleten that allows you to make bigger jumps in the state, eg: [Simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing).